# Hotels that took orders more than 5 times (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I want to SELECT the Hotels that took orders more than 5 times. for that first I need to count the number of orders each hotels took.

[This is SCHEMA of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF6Cp.png)

I tried this query to count number of orders from hotels

```
SELECT h.hotel_id , h.hotel_name , COUNT(o.hotel_id) 
FROM hotel_details h
JOIN orders o ON h.hotel_id=o.hotel_id
```

I got this output:

```
hotel_id    hotel_name    COUNT(o.hotel_id)
H1001         A2B           16
```

16 is the number total number of orders is orders table

Answer (score 0):

I'd tack on a `group by` clause and a `having` clause with a condition:

```sql
SELECT   h.hotel_id , h.hotel_name , COUNT(*) 
FROM     hotel_details h
JOIN     orders o ON h.hotel_id=o.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id , h.hotel_name 
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used a COUNT without a GROUP BY. That's why your return has only one line.

To get those one who had more than five, you can use this select as a temporary table.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT h.hotel_id , h.hotel_name , COUNT(o.order_id) as orders 
    FROM hotel_details h
    JOIN orders o ON h.hotel_id=o.hotel_id
    GROUP BY 1) a
WHERE
    orders >= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select h.hotel_id, h.hotel_name, count(o.hotel_id) as NO_OF_ORDERS
from hotel_details h
join orders o on h.hotel_id = o.hotel_id
group by o.hotel_id
having count(o.hotel_id) > 5
order by hotel_id;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)